# C# Create delegate of method where parameter types are unknown in runtime

Tags: c#, types, parameters, delegates, runtime

What I am trying to do is the following (which I necessarily don't know if it's even possible); I know a run time type. I know which method I want to invoke in run time. However, I don't know this in compile time.

The GetFunction method won't be able to create a delegate of the given methodInfo since the inparam isn't of type object.

Is there a way to create a delegate of a function where I only know a Type and a MethodInfo of the method I wish to delegate?

```
public sealed class Functions {
    public static int SetStrValue(string s) {
        // set a string
    }

    public static int SetIntValue(int i) {
        // set an int
    }
}

public sealed class GetFunctions {
    public Func<object, int> GetFunction(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo) {
        // what I would like to do.
        Func<object, int> func = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, int>), methodInfo);
        return t => func(t);
    }
}

public class InvokeFunctions {
    public void invokeFunction() {
        Type t = typeof(String);
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Functions).GetMethod("SetStrValue");
        int i = GetFunctions.GetFunction(t, methodInfo).Invoke("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: A side from the question itself why are your classes sealed? This is generally not a great idea as its basically saying 'I never ever want to extend this class or change it in any way', while many .NET classes are sealed this makes way more sense because .NET is the framework. Why do you require yours to be sealed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expression trees to create a delegate. As the compile time type is not known you could try to cast the parameter to the appropriate type at runtime.

```
public sealed class GetFunctions
{
    public static Func<object, int> GetFunction(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object), "obj");
        var convert = Expression.Convert(obj, methodInfo.GetParameters().First().ParameterType);
        var call = Expression.Call(methodInfo, convert);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, int>>(call, obj);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}

public class InvokeFunctions
{
    public void invokeFunction()
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Functions).GetMethod("SetStrValue");
        int i = GetFunctions.GetFunction(methodInfo).Invoke("hello");

        MethodInfo methodInfo2 = typeof(Functions).GetMethod("SetIntValue");
        int i2 = GetFunctions.GetFunction(methodInfo2).Invoke(1);
    }
}
```

I've removed the `Type` parameter and taken it directly from Method's first parameter, If that's not the intended behavior you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to simplify this to just:

```
public sealed class Functions 
{
    public static int SetValue<T>(T input) 
    {
        // set a value of type T
    }
}
```

And call the function with:

```
Functions.SetValue<string>("hello");
```

Or you could use a generic delegate definition if you still want to use delegates:

```
public delegate int MyDelegateFunction<T>(T input);
```

Comment: This means that I need to know in compile-time which type I'm inferring to.
The main problem here is that I'm working with an API which has different functions for different types.
I would like to cut down on the if-statements here.
In this case I must in the SetValue function still check the type and call the correct function depending on the type.