# Fastest way for Get Value of a property (Reflection) in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, delegates, reflection.emit

I want to know what is fastest way to get value (only for this problem) from an object`s property ?

after some searching I saw a post from @MarkGravell in this site

He wrote this code :

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
    private int Bar { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("cheat", typeof(int),
            new[] { typeof(object) }, typeof(Foo), true);
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(Foo));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
            ).GetGetMethod(true));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var func = (Func<object, int>)method.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<object, int>));

        var obj = new Foo(123);
        Console.WriteLine(func(obj));
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
var method = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar",
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                                  .GetGetMethod(true);
var func = (Func<Foo, int>)
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo, int>), method);
```

I changed it to

```
var pt = propertyInfo.PropertyType; // I dont know what is Type
var method = pt.GetProperty("Bar",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                                      .GetGetMethod(true);
var func = (Func<Foo, object>) // I dont know what is return type so set object !!!
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo, object>), method); // I want get value as object ?!!!
return func(entity).ToString(); // cast return value to string
```

but I got an exception

```
 Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

I dont know what is my property type It can be anything How customize code for this purpose ?

If anyone can help me in better way (fastest way) without property Type restriction please introduce it

Comment: Check out my answer in [related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670421/c-sharp-create-delegate-of-method-where-parameter-types-are-unknown-in-runtime/26670705#26670705)

Comment: You know that your type has a property called Bar but not its actual type? Sounds bad design to me, implement a common interface for that.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - problem is here (Func<Foo, T>) T must be set as same as property type but How ??? like this var pt = propertyInfo.PropertyType; (Func<Foo, pt>) !!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Delegate.CreateDelegate` will not work in this case, because you have to cast the resulting delegate to some known type, otherwise all you have is `DynamicInvoke` which is not better than direct invocation of `PropertyInfo` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke) explanation by Marc Gravell).

The most generic way I've seen which does not involve lambda expressions (like 
Sriram Sakthivel suggested) is shown by Jon Skeet [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/comment-page-1/). Building on his approach and the fact we can get the actual property return type from `PropertyInfo`, we can invent something custom-tailored for properties invocation.

First, we define an interface:

```
public interface IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis>
{
    object InvokeGet(TThis @this);
    //add void InvokeSet(TThis @this, object value) if necessary
}
```

Then, an implementation of the interface:

```
public class PropertyCallAdapter<TThis, TResult> : IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis>
{
    private readonly Func<TThis, TResult> _getterInvocation;

    public PropertyCallAdapter(Func<TThis, TResult> getterInvocation)
    {
        _getterInvocation = getterInvocation;
    }

    public object InvokeGet(TThis @this)
    {
        return _getterInvocation.Invoke(@this);
    }
}
```

The `InvokeGet` method looks mostly like the one Jon Skeet uses.

Now, to the "magic" part. We define a service which will build and cache an instance of the provider. It looks like this:

```
public class PropertyCallAdapterProvider<TThis>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis>> _instances =
        new Dictionary<string,IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis>>();

    public static IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis> GetInstance(string forPropertyName)
    {
        IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis> instance;
        if (!_instances.TryGetValue(forPropertyName, out instance))
        {
            var property = typeof(TThis).GetProperty(
                forPropertyName,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            MethodInfo getMethod;
            Delegate getterInvocation = null;
            if (property != null && (getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true)) != null)
            {
                var openGetterType = typeof(Func<,>);
                var concreteGetterType = openGetterType
                    .MakeGenericType(typeof(TThis), property.PropertyType);

                getterInvocation =
                    Delegate.CreateDelegate(concreteGetterType, null, getMethod);
            }
            else
            {
                //throw exception or create a default getterInvocation returning null
            }

            var openAdapterType = typeof(PropertyCallAdapter<,>);
            var concreteAdapterType = openAdapterType
                .MakeGenericType(typeof(TThis), property.PropertyType);
            instance = Activator
                .CreateInstance(concreteAdapterType, getterInvocation)
                    as IPropertyCallAdapter<TThis>;

            _instances.Add(forPropertyName, instance);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Here, without knowing at compile time the exact `TResult` type, we create the adapter and cache it for subsequent usage in order to prevent heavy reflection calls in the future.

That's it. You can use it in the following way:

```
PropertyCallAdapterProvider<Foo>.GetInstance("Bar").InvokeGet(fooInstance)
```

Also, you can easily extend this for property setters if necessary.

On my machine those are the results for accessing the getter in loop ten million times, using various methods, when the adapter instance is pre-fetched from the provider before entering the loop:

- 141 milliseconds for direct invocation
- 244 milliseconds for adapter invocation
- 1800 milliseconds for reflection invocation
- 8179 milliseconds for dynamic delegate invocation

Comment: Why `@this`? What means `@` in this case of use?

Comment: @Fly_NighT 'this' is a reserved word in C#. So in case you'd like to use it directly as a parameter/variable name - you will not be able to. Putting '@' at the start you are making it possible, so it is obvious what's the role of the parameter, like in `this.InvokeGet()`. But it could be called anything else - 'self', 'owner', 'subject', etc.